# Classify new instance that have new value in some features with existing model

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, missing-data, backpropagation

I have created a model with neural network (backpropagation), then i want to classify an instance.

what i've did :

- normalization with regular normalization for each features
- the values for each features is start from 0 to 1

The problem is how to classify new instance that have a new value (or some new values) in a feature (or some feature) with existing model that i made before?

Any one have solution for this condition? or some references that i can use to resolve this issue?

thanks

---

actually i have a discussion with my stochastic lecturer in my campus and he has an idea to resolve this problem by distribute the error that i got from the process when build the model. Then, the new instance can be match or see the likelihood of the instance in the distribution (like gaussian, mixture gaussian, or empirical distribution). But the problem that come in this idea is, we still have to get the error for that instance so we can see the likelihood in the distribution (or it's mean we still have to classify the instance into the existing model/function that same as the function that used in error distribution).

---

and i have a discussion with my friend too, and he has an idea to use FFT to replace the real normlization function, so the result not in certain range. But the effect is the error maybe increase by the error that come from the result of FFT function.

Comment: Are the attributes falling outside the range of the original data, or are there new classes or categories that were not originally within the data?

Comment: yes, the attributes falling outside the range of the original data, not a new class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a short-term solution, perhaps what you could do is set the value of the attribute to 0 or 1 (within the range of the original dataset) depending on the value of the attribute.

A longer-term solution would be to include such cases in future training of the neural network.  Such values may cause the values of other instances to be skewed to the left or right so some attention may be required for the preprocessing of the training data.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: for the short-term solution, it's mean i create the binary representation of my values? actually, i ever think about that, but the input nodes that i should made will be increase exponentially.

hhmm, that's good idea, it seems i'll try the long-term solution.

thank you very much for your helps :D